# How come my output is segmentation failure?

Tags: c, cs50

Im trying to make a cipher in C and am looping through 2 arrays to compare the sentence characters to alphabet ACSII values and then change those letters into the encrypted alphabet values. Here's what I've got so far:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    string test = "JTREKYAVOGDXPSNCUIZLFBMWHQ";
    string sentence = "DEEEATSXYLAPHONEELEPHANTTY";
    int alphabet[26];

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        alphabet[i] = i + 65;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++)
        {
            if (sentence[i] == alphabet[j])
            {
                sentence[i] = test[j];
            }
        }
    }

    printf("%s", sentence);

}
```

So the output is "segmentation failure". I feel like I've looped through it properly, but then this wouldn't be the first time I've felt confident but looked stupid.

Comment: What's the size of `alphabet`?  Does this code even compile on your system?

Comment: Yes I changed the array size out when messing with things. Just changed it back to how it was running before.

As for the code running I am doing it for a cs50 course and the <cs50.h> library adds a few things that arent very vanilla. I dont know if you would have access to the library from your editor.

Answer (score 2):

`valgrind` makes it easy to track this problem down:

```
==29905== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==29905==  Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0x10A01F
==29905==    at 0x109207: main (sf.c:23)
```

This is the statement `sentence[i] = test[j]`, which is attempting to write to a `const char *` (check the `typedef` of `string`).  To fix it, you'll have to give `sentence` its own copy of the data to work with, like this:

```
char sentence[] = "DEEEATSXYLAPHONEELEPHANTTY";
```

Now the assignment is writing to local data, and at least on my system, `valgrind` (and asan) run without complaint.

Comment: If `const char *` was the type then the code should fail to compile. You'll probably find it was `char *`